# CreateProcess launching edge browser

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

I have a powershell script to launch a webpage on edge browser. It works fine when you run this script from command line.

**launchWebPageFromEdge.ps1**

```
start microsoft-edge:https://www.youtube.com
```

**launchWebPageFromIE.ps1**

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
$IE = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate2($url)
$IE.visible = $true
```

My task is to launch this from a windows c++ console application. I have below piece of code for the same. The script is not launching the browser when called using CreateProcess API. I have another powershell script to launch webpage in IE. It works fine.

```
int main()
{
    std::string cmdExc = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file \"C:\\launchWebPageFromEdge.ps1\"";
    STARTUPINFO startInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
    
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
            const_cast<char *>(cmdExc.c_str()), // Command line
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            TRUE,           // Set handle inheritance to TRUE
            REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,  // creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
            &startInfo,     // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &procInfo)      // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            )
    {
        std::cout << "error\n";
        return -1;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(procInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}
```

Since IE is launching from the same code, I dont think any issues with creation flags used in createprocess API. So can some one help me here.

Comment: REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS ?  Really?

Comment: On a side note, you are leaking the `HANDLE`s output by `CreateProcess()`.  Also, have you tried using `ShellExecute/Ex()` to launch `microsoft-edge:https://www.youtube.com` directly without using a script at all?

Answer (score 0):

The [`STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa) structure is uninitialized. It is **not** an output structure, so passing in garbage there probably causes `CreateProcess` to fail. You can fix it easily like this:

```
STARTUPINFO startInfo { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
```

Note that you should close the `hProcess` and `hThread` handles returned in [`procInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information).

---

**But** you don't need PowerShell to open Edge at all.

The same can be achieved easily with [**`ShellExecuteEx`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa):

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE); // initialize COM at the start of the program

SHELLEXECUTEINFOA ex{sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOA)};
ex.lpFile = "microsoft-edge:https://www.youtube.com";
ShellExecuteExA(&ex);
```